# background image to cover the entire page

Tags: css, background-image

I have the above image[image]

I have to set it in such a way that it covers the entire page. I tried the following code.

```
margin: 0px;
    background: url(../images/common/header/Background_color.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:top center; 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
```

But what I get is this.
[image]

It is not covering the entire page. At the bottom I am getting the white space.Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this

```
background: url(../images/common/header/Background_color.png); background-repeat:repeat-x;
```

To this

```
background: url(../images/common/header/Background_color.png); background-repeat:repeat;
```

Comment: Could you please be a bit more clear? Actually I have used background-repeat. What do you want me to change?

Comment: I tried that... When I tried in that way, instead of white space in the bottom, the image is repeated. but it is not getting stretched.When I use background-repeat:repeat, instead of white space, the dark brown color which is at the top of the image is displayed.So I hope you can imagine how it looks.

Comment: repeat-x mean a background just on top
repeat-y mean a background just on bottom
repeat   mean Full size

Comment: repeat does not work.But got the solution.Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Now everything is working fine. I added the following:body, html{
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
 
}    but it is not working in IE

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: I got the answer. I added this : body, html{
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
  
}  But now it is working in all browsers other than IE.Do you have any idea how to make it work in IE

Comment: as they mentioned earlier you should add this: background-repeat: repeat;