# My body background-image does not showing up for the entire page?

Tags: css

I know this is a duplicate one it is similar to this one
[background image to cover the entire page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476780/background-image-to-cover-the-entire-page)

But I'm not getting the result my page look like this: [image: See the white background i dont how to fix ti]

I tried `repeat-x,repeat-y;background-size:cover;height:100%` but none of them worked for me...

I given my background image as inline like this

```
  <body style="padding-top:0px;background-image:url(images/bg1.jpg); repeat-x;repeat-y;">
```

Comment: Post your code, please. Image is okay, there is nothing bad.

Comment: i given it as inline like this:                <body style="padding-top:0px;background-image:url(images/bg1.jpg); repeat-x;repeat-y;">

Comment: Just do `repeat` instead of `repeat-y` .. and that should repeat on both axes.

Comment: no..it's also not working...

Comment: do u need d structure of it

Comment: body, html { height: 100%; width:100%; }  probably you body is not getting exact height.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/kE4BJRLazv52HgucsWF7S5

Comment: i gave as inline but it didnt worked ...i triedd like this......................     <body style="padding-top:0px;background-image:url(images/bg1.jpg); repeat;size: 100%;height: 100%; width:100%; ">

Comment: Ok, can we have your CSS?

Comment: No worries, sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: hey its nothing out there if u get all of my codes then u can detect it easily so dont b sorry 4 it...

Comment: Most of the CSS that you are posting is invalid: there is not `repeat-x` or `repeat-y` properties, they are values of the `background-repeat` property (that has a default value of `repeat` so it's not really needed in this case); there is also no `size` property that you can set to 100%; And you should avoid the inline styling altogether... Even with all that, [the code works fine on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nd2jxykx/2/), so I guess that other CSS styles (that you are not sharing) are affecting the display and breaking it